# MongDB-JSON document size >16MB throws error when saving

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

We have few JSON Documents those are greater than 16 MB when saving to MongoDB, iam getting **"Payload document size is larger than maximum of 16MB"** as an error.Is there an approach to store this documents along with documents that are less than 16MB  in the same collection,so that my queries will be seamless.I have explored GridFS option provided by mongodb,but i have queries that need to support aggregation pipelines,but GridFS doesn't support Aggregation and sort by etc.Can someone help here.

I tried using GridFS,but GridFS doen't seems to support Aggregation and sort by.I want better approach to store documents >16MB in the same collection without much complexity.

Comment: there is no other option. Effectively gridfs simply split a big message on smaller chunks. It's the only way to store bigger documents. If you don't want using gridfs, you can do the same splitting logic somehow on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Store metadata in a separate collection. By storing the metadata associated with the GridFS files in a separate collection, you can use the full range of MongoDB aggregation and sorting features. [Official docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/#std-label-gridfs-files-collection).

Comment: Thank you very much,can you point me to any reference for both the approaches please.

Comment: Answer updated with links

Comment: Why do you refer to sharding? The max. size of BSON document is still 16 MiByte, no matter if sharding is used or not.

Comment: Ah thanks @WernfriedDomscheit. You are correct. Sharding alone will not solve the problem of storing documents > 16MB, as the max size BSON doc is still 16MB